# Scroll Controller And Refresh Indicator not work

Tags: dart, flutter

i'hve a flutter project,
when i tried to make a invinite listview but scroll controller not work, no error.
also refresh indicator not work to, but if primary false on listview refresh work.

for information, my listview not work if primary set to false, because this listview inside listview on main.dart
code

```
List<dynamic> list = [];
ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();

void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _loadData();
    _scrollController.addListener(() {
      if (_scrollController.position.pixels ==
          _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent - 50) {
        _loadData();
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _scrollController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  Future<dynamic> _loadData() {
    var offset = list.length;
    return Api().postData("resto",
        body: <String, String>{"offset": "$offset"}).then((dynamic res) {
      if (res["error"]) throw new Exception(res["msg"]);
      setState(() {
        list.addAll(res['data']);
      });
    });
  }

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
      children: <Widget>[
        FlatButton(
          child: Text(
            "Filter Popularity",
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
          ),
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
        Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: list.length == 0 ? _shimmer() : _listResto()),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _listResto() {
    return ListView.builder(
      controller: _scrollController,
      primary: false,
      shrinkWrap: true,
      itemCount: list == null ? 0 : list.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, i) {
```

Comment: The issue is still open. You can check the issue in github:) https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/22180

Answer (score 26):

add `physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics()` to RefreshIndicator

```
body: RefreshIndicator(
        onRefresh: _refreshList,
        child: ListView.builder(
          controller: _scrollController,
          physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          itemCount: items.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(
                title: Text('Item ${items[index]}'),
              ),
        ),
      )
```

Comment: This answer is worth more than a +1 vote. I was almost losing my insane while trying the combinations of RefreshIndicator and CustomScollView.